# How To Show Current Location in URL Custom Google Map by Android Eclipse Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

I Have a Create Android Application With Eclipse , But I Have a Problem ...
I Want to go my custom google map with URl and see device's current location in my map on the device

For Example :
I have a button in one of pages on app , when touch button in the page go to the my custom google map (URL) and show the device's current location.

tanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Get current Latitude and Longitude using LocationManager.

simply replace the values in the following string with my start and current Lng/Lat

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_ADD&amp;daddr=DEST_ADD&amp;ll=START_ADD
```

Then  launch the url like this in android, which will let the user choose to either use the browser or their native maps app:

```
    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_ADD&amp;daddr=DEST_ADD&amp;ll=START_ADD";

startActivity( new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url)));
```

Comment: i want to know exactly , how do it ?